# How do I arrange similar data from multiple json files but in different format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json

I am new to JSON and trying to develop a comparison table with data coming from 2 different `JSON` files as follows.

**Json File 1**

```
"data":[
    {
        "EffectiveDate": "2017-04-01T00:00:00Z",
        "IncludedQuantity": 0,
        "Category": "VM",
        "Id": "d0bf9053",
        "Name": "Element1",
        "Rates": {
            "0": 0.04
        },
        "Region": "US",
        "Status": "Active",
        "SubCategory": "S1",
        "Tags": [],
        "Unit": "Hours"
    },
    {
        "EffectiveDate": "2017-02-01T00:00:00Z",
        "IncludedQuantity": 0,
        "Category": "DS",
        "Id": "8b7672d4",
        "Name": "Element2",
        "Rates": {
            "0": 4.0177
        },
        "Region": "UK",
        "Status": "Active",
        "SubCategory": "S2",
        "Tags": [],
        "Unit": "Days"
    }]
```

**Json File 2**

```
"data":{
    "d0bf9053":{
        "EffectiveDate": "2017-04-01T00:00:00Z",
        "IncludedQuantity": 0,
        "Category": "VM",
        "Id": "d0bf9053",
        "Attributes":{
           "Name": "Element1",
           "Rates": {
               "0": 5
           },
           "Region": "US",
           "Status": "Active",
           "SubCategory": "S1",
           "Tags": [],
           "Unit": "Hours"
           }
    },
    "8b7672d4":{
        "EffectiveDate": "2017-02-01T00:00:00Z",
        "IncludedQuantity": 0,
        "Category": "DS",
        "Id": "8b7672d4",
        "Attributes":{
           "Name": "Element2",
           "Rates": {
              "0": 1
           },
           "Region": "UK",
           "Status": "Active",
           "SubCategory": "S2",
           "Tags": [],
           "Unit": "Days"
           }
    }}
```

Now I have to read this data and merge it to create a comparison based on rates and categories. I have created a `Dot.Net Console Application` and trying to use `SQL Server` to store the information. Now I am able to read `JSON File 1` easily. But I am facing difficulty in storing values from `JSON File 2`. How do I solve this or am I wrong somewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To know what is wrong we'd have to know what you are doing (your code) and more details about what your goal is.

Comment: @Crowcoder my goal is to merge this 2 json files in a single table and display to the user

Comment: You'll probably want to use Newtonsoft's `JObject.Parse()` since your JSON is not a friendly format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have dynamic property names in the second JSON file (Json File 2) and you are probably having trouble deserializing that JSON into a .Net Class, right?

Here are some examples that you can use to deserialize both Json1 and Json2 Types:

```
public class dataJson1
{
    public List<Detail> data { get; set; }
}

public class dataJson2
{
    public Dictionary<string, Detail> data { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public int IncludedQuantity { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    //add the rest of the props here
}
```

That should get you started, once it's deserialized into those Objects, comparing them should be trivial.

Comment: Each time I call the API for Json File 2 I get the same property name as they wont change but I am not able to deserialize that JSON

Comment: OK, can you post some code where you attempt the deserialize?

Comment: I haven't coded for the 2nd file yet. Let me try this. Thanks @Janus

Comment: Any luck @saikatmukherjee? Give me a shout if I can help

Comment: Thanks a ton @Janus I was able to map it :)